Issues when calculating average for two weeks with PromQL
I need to write a PromQL query on my Grafana dashboard that calculates average CPU usage of pods over two weeks for a specific container name and namespace.
I used to have this query:
sum(
    sum(sum_over_time(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu", namespace=~"mynamespace",container=~"mycontainer"}[2w])) by (pod) 
    /
    sum(count_over_time(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu", namespace=~"mynamespace",container=~"mycontainer"}[2w])) by (pod) 
)

Unfortunately, it is heavily affected by number of pods (as I figured out lately, when my dashboard started showing results one or two magnitudes more than it should).
I decided to rewrite the query with the following logic: I need to calculate how much CPU all pods with a specific container and namespace labels request at any given moment, and then take an average of that over two weeks. This resulted into something like this:
avg_over_time(
    sum(
        sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu", namespace=~"mynamespace",container=~"mycontainer"}) by (pod) 
        /
        count(kube_pod_container_resource_requests{resource="cpu", namespace=~"mynamespace",container=~"mycontainer"}) by (pod) 
    )
[2w])

I really like its results when used without avg_over_time, since it returns some sensible numbers. However, I need average of those sensible values, and adding avg_over_time function returns
ReadObject: expect { or , or } or n, but found B, error found in #1 byte of ...|Bad Gateway|..., bigger context ...|Bad Gateway|...

While I do recognise that this error may come from the infrastructure itself, I find the prospect highly unlikely, since it was written by many people far more experienced than me. Thus, my query requires some changes, and I would greatly appreciate any ideas as to what I may try.
